# No audio with SDL/C++

Tags: c++, audio, sdl, sdl-mixer

```
void LoadMusic(string path);

Mix_Music* gMusic = NULL;


        LoadMusic("Music/bubble-bobble.mp3");
        if(Mix_PlayingMusic() == 0)
        {
            Mix_PlayMusic(gMusic, -1);
        }

    if(Mix_OpenAudio(44100, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 2048) < 0)
    {
        cout << "Mixer could not initialise. error: " << Mix_GetError();
        return false;
    }


    Mix_FreeMusic(gMusic);
    gMusic = NULL;

void LoadMusic(string path)
{
    gMusic = Mix_LoadMUS(path.c_str());

    if(gMusic == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Failed to load background music! Error: " << Mix_GetError() << endl;
    }
}
```

Been following a tutorial on how to get audio to work with my game, think something has gone wrong somewhere as it's not playing any sound at all. Not 100% where this is going wrong but does anyone have an idea what I have done wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: There's a lot of unrelated code in your program, at least unrelated to your problem and this question. Please make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us instead.

Comment: Took out the code that's not needed. If you need the full code it's here http://pastebin.com/MdQuHnjt. It might be that I have the code the in the wrong places

Comment: very simple audio player in c++ : https://github.com/abdullahfarwees/Wav_Audio_player_SDL

Answer (score 4):

You don't specify your operating system and other important context, but...

If you are running your build under *Windows*, you might have encountered the same problem as I did:

Surprisingly, the *SDL* library requires an environment variable in order to play audio at all.

Try adding `SDL_AUDIODRIVER=waveout` (or alternatively, `SDL_AUDIODRIVER=dsound`) to your environment (under *Windows*).

Comment: Or, if you're on SDL2 on Windows, you'll need `SDL_AUDIODRIVER=directsound` or `SDL_AUDIODRIVER=winmm`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, was following a tutorial to create my own **C++** simple audio player, and it wasn't working. I made it display the names of the available playback devices, but none of them seemed to work, until I added the *environment variable* as stated here.

It worked fine in Windows 10, after adding to my system an environment Variable named `SDL_AUDIODRIVER=directsound` .